# Displaying List TEXT not VALUE when using DisplayFor in HTML Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an almost complete solution but I am stuck at the last hurdle!

Here is my DropDownList helper

```
    // DropDown helper
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownInputFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListValues, string DefaultText, object HTMLAttributes, bool CanEdit)
    {
        if (CanEdit == true)
        {
            // return a dropdown
            return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, ListValues, DefaultText, HTMLAttributes);
        }
        else
        {
            // just return the text (no editor)                
            return htmlHelper.DisplayFor(expression);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am returning the helper depending on if the user can edit or not. In this case, if they can edit then we return the DropDownList and if they cannot edit we just return the DisplayFor.

The issue with this however is that the DisplayFor shows the 'value' (foreign key) as opposed to the text of the DropDown.

Any suggestions on how to Display the text not the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that if CanEdit is false, you want just to show the text coresponding to the value in your ListValues. For that you can try something like:

```
// DropDown helper
        public static MvcHtmlString DropDownInputFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListValues, string DefaultText, object HTMLAttributes, bool CanEdit)
        {            
            if (CanEdit == true)
            {
                // return a dropdown
                return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, ListValues, DefaultText, HTMLAttributes);
            }
            else
            {
                // just return the text (no editor) 
                //but first make sure you have a valid value in your list and show it               
                var selected = ListValues.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Selected == true);
                if (selected != null)
                    return htmlHelper.DisplayName(selected.Text);
                else
                    //here you can just put the default selected item if no valid value is found
                    return htmlHelper.DisplayName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));//or whatever defaultvalue you want 
            }
        }
```

The thing is that the text is included in your ListValues, and the selected item should match your expression value.

Comment: Thank you! This didn't solve it 100% as none of the ListValues are selected at this point. However I just passed in the value (from the Model in the view) and used that to determine the text and it works perfectly.